# How to get python to go back to start of loop and not use random?

Tags: python, loops, random, numbers, break

I'm a bit new to python and was giving myself a task, I wanted a number guessing game that gets you to guess four numbers and the program will keep telling you how many numbers you guess right till you guess the full list of numbers.

```
running = True
import random
def compareLists(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))
def start():
    rNums =  random.sample(range(10), 4)
    gNums = []

    print("Get ready to guess 4 numbers!")
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x = int(input("Guess: "))
        gNums.append(x)

    print("You guessed: ", gNums)
    comparison = len(compareLists(rNums, gNums))

    while gNums and rNums:
        if gNums != rNums:
            print("You guessed " + str(comparison) + " numbers right, keep guessing!")
            break
        elif gNums == rNums:
            print("What amazing luck!")
while running:
    start()
```

The problem is that when I use a break a new list of 4 numbers is created, I want python to just go back to the start of the loop and not make a whole new list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the

```
rNums =  random.sample(range(10), 4)
```

outside the loop and pass rNums to start. This way you will have the same four numbers in the list. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `continue`. Try it with a toy example:

```
i = 0;
while i < 10:
   i += 1
   if i % 2 == 0:
      continue
   print i
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly? Having trouble wrapping my head round it

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of minimizing the amount of loops going on in your code, I would probably first pop your random numbers in a dictionary.

Something like this (probably more efficient way of doing this...but it's the first thing that popped in my head):

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(random.sample(range(10), 4))
```

Start your while loop, and keep asking the user to guess. Every time they make a right guess, just perform this operation:

```
d.pop(correctly_guessed_num)
```

Once your dictionary is empty, you are done and you break the loop.

**EDIT** adding my quick stab at the implementation. Not fully thought through, might be some edge cases that break this...but this is the overall idea. Hope it helps.

```
from collections import Counter
import random

d = Counter(random.sample(range(1, 10), 4))
size = len(d) - 1

while True:
    x = int(input("Guess: "))

    if size == 0:
        print("you guessed them all, way to go")
        break

    if x not in d:
        print("keep going buddy")
        continue
    else:
        d.pop(x)
        size -= 1
        print("A right guess")
```

Comment: I've used dictionaries very little but tried your solution anyway, and I most likely didn't do it right but thanks for answering

Comment: I'll provide some code in my reply for you to help out. Let me know if you have any other questions.